# Find a cell on edge of rectangular grid

Tags: java

The method public static boolean onEdge(int n, int numRows, int numCols) should give TRUE if n is on the edge of a rectangular grid (numRows X numCols) and false if n is in interior. For example, (0,4,4) should give true or (2,4,4) also true; but (6,4,4) is false.

```
public static boolean onEdge(int n, int numRows, int numCols) 
  {
      int originalRow = 0;

      if ((n < 0) || (numRows < 0) || (numCols < 0))
          return false;

      else if (n == originalRow) 
          return true;

      else if (n == numRows)
          return true;

      else
          return false;


  }
```

Comment: how is n mapped to row and column?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is your code not working in the way you expect? Please edit your question to include what went wrong and what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple arithmetics:

```
public static boolean onEdge(int n, int numRows, int numCols)
{
    int row = n / numCols; // int / int divides to floor
    int column = n % numCols; // column within row

    // check if n is in the beginning or final row
    if (row == 0 || row == numRows - 1)
        return true;

    // check if n is in the first or last column
    if (column == 0 || column == numCols -1)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

You can find the row number `n` is in by dividing n through the amount of columns you have. `int`/`int` always returns an `int` value, the floor one (3/2 = 1).

You can find the column number `n` is in by getting the rest of the above division using the modulo operator.

When you have both values, you can check if `n` is in either the first or the last row or the first or the last column. If not, it is in the "middle" of your field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there is a bug in the code... what if (5,3,3) so it should return false but the code is returning true

Comment: No, it should return true as 5 is the last index of the second row. First row: 0, 1, 2; second row: 3, 4, 5; third row: 6, 7, 8; the only index that should return false for a 3x3 grid is 4.

Comment: Alright now I see. Thanks! Last question: does it have any particular formula or you just came with it immediately?

Comment: It's experience I think. Such mathematics often applies to 2d values.